# My node express app can't connect locally to mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using macOs. I have followed the web dev tutorial on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NrHkjlWVhM. It is a simple node app with the ff npm installations:

- express
- pug
- mongoose ("^5.9.26")
- --save-dev nodemon

Note that MongoDB is not installed in my computer as it was not required by the tutorials.

Here is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blog', {
     useNewUrlParser: true, 
     useUnifiedTopology: true
}).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

I have tried changing the server address to the ff without success

- mongodb://localhost:27017/blog
- mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/blog
- mongodb://127.0.0.1/blog

and would continually get the ff error log. How do I get around this?

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/Dave/Desktop/apps/test-blog/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:827:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/Dave/Desktop/apps/test-blog/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:335:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Dave/Desktop/apps/test-blog/server.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note that MongoDB is not installed in my computer as it was not required by the tutorials

The MongoDB URI `mongodb://localhost:27017` is pointing to the local computer. In other words, a MongoDB instance must be installed on the local computer, in order for the Node script to connect to one.

Note that in general, the `localhost` domain and its equivalent IP address `127.0.0.1` are reserved for services running on the local computer. For example, in this case, a local MongoDB instance is expected to run at the `localhost` domain at the default `27017` port, as indicated in the error message.

> MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017